# Vue Router not working properly and adds a #

Tags: json, api, vue.js, vue-router

I have a main app page component with a search bar. The Search results that come back is in cards And I am looking to set up a "Click here to view more detail" that would be placed in each card. And it would link to the Details page of the one result clicked. How do I link these components on Vue and if the id could be passed? I am hoping that upon click of the button the component renders on the same page and not a new tab.

Once I click on "click here" It updates the link to http://localhost:8081/#/{name:'Details',%20params:%20{id:%20result._gddid}}

and

I get an [Vue warn]: Property or method "results" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Thank you!

app.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Header/>
    <SearchForm v-on:search="search"/>
    <SearchResults
      v-if="results.length > 0"
      v-bind:results="results"
      v-bind:reformattedSearchString="reformattedSearchString"/>
    <Details
      v-bind:results="results"
     />

    <Pagination
      v-if="results.length > 0"
      v-bind:prevPageToken="api.prevPageToken"
      v-bind:next_page="api.scrollId"
      v-on:prev-page="prevPage"
      v-on:next-page="nextPage"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from './components/layout/Header';
import SearchForm from './components/SearchForm';
import SearchResults from './components/SearchResults';
import Details from './components/Details'
import Pagination from './components/Pagination';
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Header,
    SearchForm,
    SearchResults,
    Details,
    Pagination
  },

   data() {
    return {
      results: [],
      reformattedSearchString: '',
      api: {
        baseUrl: 'https://test.org/api/v1/articles?',
        max: 25,
        q: '',
        prevPageToken: '',
        scrollId: ''
      }
    };
  },


   methods: {
    search(searchParams) {
      this.reformattedSearchString = searchParams.join(' ');
      this.api.q = searchParams.join('+');
      const { baseUrl, q, max} = this.api;
      const apiUrl = `${baseUrl}&term=${q}&title_like=${q}&recent&max=${max}&full_results`;
      this.getData(apiUrl);

    },

    prevPage() {
      const { baseUrl, q, max, prevPageToken } = this.api;
      const apiUrl = `${baseUrl}&term=${q}&title_like=${q}&max=${max}&pageToken=${prevPageToken}`;
      this.getData(apiUrl);
    },

    nextPage() {
      const { baseUrl, q, max,scrollId } = this.api;
      const apiUrl = `${baseUrl}&term=${q}&title_like=${q}&max=${max}&recent&full_results&scroll_id=${scrollId}`;
      this.getData(apiUrl);
    },

    getData(apiUrl) {
      axios
        .get(apiUrl)
        .then(res => {
          this.results = res.data.success.data;
          this.api.prevPageToken = res.data.success.data.prevPageToken;
          this.api.next_page = res.data.scrollId;
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }  
  }
};
</script>
```

SearchResults.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container mb-3">
    <div class="d-flex mb-3">
      <div class="mr-auto">
        <h3>Search Results for "{{ reformattedSearchString }}"</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group ml-auto" role="group">
        <button
          @click="changeDisplayMode('grid')"
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
          v-bind:class="{ active: displayMode === 'grid' }"
        >
          <i class="fas fa-th"></i>
        </button>
        <button
          @click="changeDisplayMode('list')"
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
          v-bind:class="{ active: displayMode === 'list' }"
        >
          <i class="fas fa-list"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card-columns" v-if="displayMode === 'grid'">
      <div class="card" v-bind:key="result._gddid" v-for="result in results">
        <ArticleGridItem v-bind:result="result"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <div class="card mb-2" v-bind:key="result._gddid" v-for="result in results">
        <ArticleListItem v-bind:result="result"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-2" v-bind:key="result._gddid" v-for="result in results">
        <Details v-bind:result="result"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ArticleListItem from './ArticleListItem';
import ArticleGridItem from './ArticleGridItem';
import Details from './Details';


export default {
  name: 'SearchResults',
  components: {
    ArticleListItem,
    ArticleGridItem,
    Details,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      title: 'Search Results',
      displayMode: 'grid'
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeDisplayMode(displayMode) {
      this.displayMode = displayMode;
    }
  },
  props: ['results', 'reformattedSearchString']
};
</script>

<style scoped>
button:focus {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
</style>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import moment from 'moment'



Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.filter('formatDate', function (value) {
  if (!value) return ''
  return moment(value.toString()).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm')
})

Vue.use(VueRouter)

import Details from './components/Details';

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
     path: '/Details/:id',
     name: 'Details',
     component: Details
   }
 ]
})


new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

ArticleListItem.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="card-body"> 
    <h6 class="card-text">{{ result.title }}</h6>
      <p class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"
      >{{ result.publisher }} | {{ result.journal }} | {{ result.year }}</p>
      <a :href="'https://test.org/api/articles?docid=' + result._gddid" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-download"  alt="Download"> </i>
      </a>
        <router-link dark to="{name:'Details', params: {id: result._gddid}}">
              Click here for more Details
        </router-link>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ArticleListItem',
  props: ['result'],  
}
</script>
```

Details.vue

```
 <template>
    <div class="Details">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" v-for="result in results" :key="result._gddid"> 
                    <div v-if="id == result._gddid">
                        <h1>{{result.title}}</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>      
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>    
</template>
<script>
 export default {
  name: 'Details',
  props: ['result'],

};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Once I click on "click here" It updates the link to http://localhost:8081/#/{name:'Details',%20params:%20{id:%20result._gddid}}

Glancing over the code it appears that within *ArticleListItem.vue* the router-link's *to* attr isn't bound so it's treated as a string.

Currently: `to="{name:'Details', params: {id: result._gddid}}"`

Try: `:to="{name:'Details', params: {id: result._gddid}}"` so it's passed as an object.

---

> I get an [Vue warn]: Property or method "results" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Within *Details.vue* you have `props: ['result'],` but in the *v-for* it looks for *results* which isn't defined within *data()* nor within *props*.

---

As for the *#* appearing, vue-router's default mode is `hash`, if you're not wanting to use *#* you can set it to history via:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```

But beware you'll need a server running to handle the routing; You can find more info at https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-history-mode

Comment: Great thank you!! I still can't figure out the v-for part. In my SearchResults.vue I have a v-for but should I not have it in there?

Comment: the v-for i was referencing is in the Details.vue file you provided. it's using a v-for over results but the props for Details.vue have "result".

Comment: So the ArticleListItem.vue has props: result so I figured that would work @subhaze

Comment: correct but it appears Details.vue needs results looking at the code for Details.vue but it's not given results, it's given "result" but expects "results" here `<div class="col-md-12" v-for="result in results" :key="result._gddid">`

Comment: Still can't get the click to work. I changed it to results for the props but method "id" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Comment: the click part is obviously missing something? @subhaze

Comment: Ahh... yeah, so looking through code samples again no props passed in the route. hmm... You may want to start looking into some form of state management, but, in a pinch you might be able to remove all props from `Details.vue` and just do a computed prop for `results`. Something like `computed: { results(){ return this.$parent.$data.results } }` this should pull in the results from `App.vue` which from the looks of it, you're storing there.